# Dock only shows on the primary display

Tags: display, dock, macos

I have a two display setup arranged as shown in figure.

I can see the dock only on my primary display and only when the application it hosts is not in fullscreen mode.
My dock is configured to appear only when I move the pointer to the bottom of the screen.

[image: My dual display setup]

Can I configure my Mac to display the dock on the display I am currently working, even if it hosts a fullscreen application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just figured out that there is a special gesture to do that.

I need to swipe all the way to the bottom of the touchpad and then hold my finger for a while.

That gesture does the trick both on the secondary screen and on fullscreen applications.

Comment: Yea, I noticed it needs that on full-screen applications and I hate it! Any way to turn it off? I just want to throw my mouse down and get my dock.

Comment: I don't know, but it would be great because this new gesture is kind of annoying. Moreover I noticed that this gesture "moves the dock". After I execute it, if the application is not in fullscreen, it is enough to move the pointer to the bottom of the screen.